# picker view constraints works on simulator but not on iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, uipickerview

I've build an app in which I have many picker view, I've set up the constraints (pin Constraints) for these picker views as well as other view and they work perfectly on the simulator (on all devices).

The problem is:
I loaded the app on an iPhone 4S and the constraints for the picker views don't work (they show up without a height restriction).
anyone came across such problem?
Thanks

Comment: can you mention what os version the iPhone 4S has?

Comment: @spirographer it run iOS 8.3

Comment: have you tried the iOS 8.3 simulator for the app then? you can download and install them from the more simulators... item in the dropdown menu for choosing app debug targets in the main xcode window.

Comment: @spirographer Thanks for the tip, I installed it and the same issue appears now on the simulator!! How can i tackle this issue?

Comment: well I just tested it on many iOs versions and it only works well for the iOs 9.1.
I can't believe that Apple didn't include a way to adjust the height for older versions.

Comment: iOS 9 has better defaults for the picker view, so you need to manually set the height constraint for older iOS versions for it to work properly across all versions.